# Phonegap/Cordova camera.getPicture behaves oddly when placed in subview

Tags: cordova, xamarin.ios, cordova-2.0.0

I am creating an app where I use Cordova Cleaver as a subview within an app. Depending on the state of the app, we may have a toolbar at the bottom of the view. When we hide the toolbar, we increase the size of the Cordova view so that it takes the whole view (minus the status bar at the top). This is done because we may reuse the Webview to display content from arbitrary locations, and provide cordova native functionality if those pages support it, specifically if they implement our apps API.

Full disclosure, I am using MonoTouch because these is some large and complex business logic we would like to use cross platform, but in terms of the views, and how they're created, I'm only using the iOS libraries (with the monotouch C# wrappers), but this should not cause an issue.

So just to make it clear, we have our AppViewController, which contains a toolbar, and a our WebViewController (a subclass of CDVViewController). The toolbar is used to allow some functions in the native app like adding a favorite, or returning to the main app page.

This has seemed to work well, but there is a problem in one specific case (so far at least). When we run Cordova's camera.getPicture command, the Status bar is hidden, but the camera view  appears to still be placed with the status bar space at the top, cutting off the cancel button. On the iPhone, if you hit the camera button or cancel, it also seems to invoke the toolbar buttons below this view.[image: Camera picker view with the status bar space remaining at the top].

To overcome this problem, I subclassed CDVCamera, and overrode the TakePicture, DidCancelImagePicker, DidFinishPickingMediaWithInfo, DidFinishPickingImage methods, so that when we started the take picture tasks, it would hide the status bar, and the toolbar, and resize the WebViewController's view, and the WebView by association, so that they would effectively be the only views. This worked, but we started to experience another related bug. The Camera Picker would display perfectly fine the first time, but if we were to cancel the picker, and reinvoke (while in landscape), it would sporadically show the picker with a big black section to the right. When in this state, we can rotate it any way we want, and it would still appear as a square. Cancelling and opening in Portrait seems to work with 100% success, but landscape seems to have varied reliability. [image: Camera picker view with large black region unusable]. Hitting the camera view within this view seems to take the picture ok, but as you can see, it's as though the camera picker is zoomed in on a subsection of the image. [image: Full view of the picture taken under the odd camera picker].

I tried to base my efforts on the the [Embed Cordova/PhoneGap as a Subview in your Native iOS Application](http://devgirl.org/2012/11/15/embed-cordovaphonegap-in-your-native-ios-app/) by Holly Schinsky, but perhaps I'm doing something in the wrong way, am missing some configuration, or there is a better way I should be doing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Additional useful information:

- Cordova 2.4.0 is what I'm using so far, but tried 2.3.0 and 2.7.0, and the issue didn't appear any different.

Comment: Why are you embedding a Cordova camera control instead of using the native camera API (or the Xamarin.Mobile API)?  What does this approach gain you?

Comment: To make a long story short, we already have a fairly mature HTML5 based application, but to enable some specific use cases, we need to be able to wrap it in a native app to provide that functionality. 
Cordova allows us to invoke the camera from the javascript in the HTML5 based app.

Comment: can you show your code of how you implemented the AddChildViewController with the cordova viewController, im having the same issue with my camera.

Comment: @JasonG: Are you loading your Cordova view as a subview within your main view controller?

Answer (score 1):

After several weeks on this issue, today, I found the solution. Not that I'm sure anyone will ever need it, but if they do, the problem that I had was that I was taking my Cordova ViewController's view, and adding it to my larger Applications ViewController's view. What I was missing was adding my Cordova ViewController as a child view controller using `AddChildViewController`. By having the Cordova ViewController as a child, it is forwarded the rotation and other application events that it required. Now every thing works perfectly. Wish I would have found this weeks ago.

For others experiencing similar issues, If you are, like me, creating a new Cordova ViewController that you will embed within your own View Controller, something like this should work.

This is the subset of the mono involved (I used xib for my interface)

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    this.webViewer = new CDVViewController();

    // If you have a start page you'd like to load, enter it here
    // Or leave it commented to use what's configured in the config.xml
    // this.webViewer.StartPage = "";

    AddChildViewController(this.webViewer);

    this.View.add(this.webvViewer.View);
}
```

I hope that helps.

Based on Jason G's code, I tried to write what my code would be in Objective-C. Please edit this if you find an error.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    webView = [CDVViewController new];

    // If you have a start page you'd like to load, enter it here
    // Or leave it commented to use what's configured in the config.xml
    // webView.startPage = "";

    [self addChildViewController:webView];

    [self.view addSubview:webView.view];
}
```

Note that this isn't all of the code you'll likely want. You'll also likely want to set up the View frame for `self.view`. The key here was the `addChildViewController` which will by default forward important application events on to the child ViewControllers.

Answer (score 1):

Yea here is what my code looks like, I pretty much have it opening a new subview on top of the old, and when i need to refresh I couldnt find any other option then to kill the subview and recall it, it works out okay i guess. But the main thing I was trying to flush out was the camera offset when it opens up.

my H,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ifaddrs.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>

@interface RSV : CDVViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
  IBOutlet CDVViewController *webView;
  IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityind;
}
- (IBAction)Refresh:(id)sender;
@end
```

my M,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  webView = [CDVViewController new]; 
  webView.startPage = @"Website";
  [self.webView addSubview:webView.view];
  webView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
   [activityind startAnimating];
    [self.webView addSubview: activityind];
    [self Malelka];
}

-(void) Malelka
{
    if ([webView.spaghetti isEqualToString:@"TRUE"]){
       [activityind removeFromSuperview];
    }else{
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(Malelka) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
}

- (IBAction)Refresh:(id)sender {
    webView = [CDVViewController new];
    webView.startPage = @"Website";   
    [self.webView addSubview:webView.view];
    webView.view.frame = CGRectMake (0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,(self.view.frame.size.height -44));
    [activityind startAnimating];
    [self.webView addSubview: activityind];
    [self Malelka];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)subview {}
- (void)loading {}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];}

@end
```